# 321-avoiding and parity-alternating permutations

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations, enumerative-combinatorics, pattern-avoidance

It is classical that 321-avoiding permutations are enumerated by the Catalan numbers.

A permutation is *parity-alternating* if it sends even integers to even integers, and odd integers to odd. I am interested in the number of 321-avoiding parity-alternating permutations. (123-avoidance is also of interest).
The four other patterns of length 3 [are easy to enumerate.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.08168.pdf)

**Example:**
The sequence for 321-avoiding permutations of size $n=1,2,3,...$ is
$$
1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 22, 44, 89, 185, 382, 808, 1702, 3635, 7779, \dotsc
$$
and this is <s>not in the OEIS at the moment</s> [A354208](https://oeis.org/A354208).
For example, $[1, 2, 3, 4]$, and $[3, 4, 1, 2]$ are the two parity-alternating permutations of size 4 which also avoids 321.

These numbers are generated by first computing all
321-avoiding permutations (via a Catalan recursion) and then selecting the parity-alternating ones. We do not have an efficient formula for generating the numbers above.

**Question:** *Can one find some more efficient way of generating the above sequence?*
A generating function, or a recursion?

Note: For odd $n$, there is a bijection between 123 and 321-avoiding, parity-alternating permutations, by taking the reverse

Comment: Is the even terms [A150268](http://oeis.org/A150268)?

Comment: @LeechLattice No, I think I managed to get a term which did not match; (let's see if I can compute it again), and I think we spent a long time trying to prove these were the same (but weren't).

Comment: Do you get the 16th term as 7779?

Comment: I think it should be possible to use a search-based approach to generate terms more efficiently (but still effectively by generating the permutations themselves). For instance, if p is a permutation of [n] of this type then either p(1) = 1 (and then we 'know' how many of that sort there are since the remainder is effectively a shifted version of a previous case), or p(1) is an odd number greater than 1. Then, p(2) must be an even number greater than p(1) (since the value 1 must occur before any other value less than p(1)). Perhaps though your filtering already takes this into account.

Comment: @LeechLattice Yes, that's correct, I just computed two more terms, but it takes a while to get those.

Comment: @MichaelAlbert Nah, my code is not that smart, it is rather primitive (and runs in Mathematica). For better results, then one would probably do it in some compiled language and not store all permutations generated.
As a general comment: it makes sense to break the sequence by odd or even indexed terms. This is very natural for the other patterns.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson I'm just fiddling with a bit of Java code for doing this (it's a type of problem with which I have some familiarity!) I may have some more numbers in a few hours (indeed one will not store permutations, just a depth-first search effectively).

Comment: Excuse me for being hopelessly ignorant, but whit is the definition of a 321-avoideng permutation?

Comment: @PerAlexandersson OK, fewer bugs than anticipated. Still not fully optimised code (doing a breadth-first rather than depth-first search) but a longer list of values is: 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 22, 44, 89, 185, 382, 808, 1702, 3635, 7779, 16736, 36229, 78466, 171238, 373203, 819186, 1795611, 3958662

Comment: @bof A permutation is 321-avoiding if, when you read its sequence of values you never encounter a subsequence (not necessarily consecutive) of three in decreasing order. Another characterisation (not immediately obvious!) is that its sequence of values can be partitioned into two increasing sequences. See [wikipedia on permutation patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_pattern) for more.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson Here are the values through n=29 (more or less the limit of my patience at this point) using a simple DFS (there are ways to refine it which would dig out more terms but I'm not sure it's worth it). Incidentally, it appears the exponential growth rate is about 2 which would make sense from the heuristic that each element has a 1/2 chance of being the right parity, so we expect about 4^n/2^n. 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 22, 44, 89, 185, 382, 808, 1702, 3635, 7779, 16736, 36229, 78466, 171238, 373203, 819186, 1795611, 3958662, 8721086, 19294525, 42691298, 94733886, 210379132

Comment: [Simple DFS in Python](https://tio.run/##VY/BboQwDETv@Yo5JiKVlq16QaI/skIV6poSKRiUBCn5ehrT5dCTk7Fn/LyVNK/8/raVrRzHkyZEGsP3rGeLHC1KNJ2Cm8BrqkJ9ozjyT6R986RN/QdKe2Cl4NFjcaxzfNwGsdZixFsiyEfC2VCY1gBnMxyDeF8ojImqSRbJdEbf16w6lPGJWdTTkrw4XnjLmCtiNrJGSB@dG5paXNN2w5l0gepsTZO8UkqumzRL94/5CrtZeBeTDiP/kG4tN629G/NPvV@qUUpoWGBerQ@J3ILjpNki7otuT@IvmZGNxhzHLw)

Comment: @PeterTaylor Nice!

Comment: Very nice ideas for generating these numbers!

Comment: This may not be relevant, but the parity-alternating property reminds me of [chess tableaux](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v11i2a3).

Comment: I reworked to use bitmasks instead of lists for efficiency, and can extend @MichaelAlbert's list by six values: 468084856, 1042703207, 2325575076, 5193931583, 11609749877, 25986720374. The ratio between successive terms appears to be growing without bound, but if you consider the sequence r(n) = (nth Catalan number)/(nth term of the sequence of interest), the term ratio r(n+1)/r(n) appears to be converging on a value slightly above 1.71. (Another two terms would help to clarify, but I estimate a calculation time of about 24 hours).

Comment: @PerAlexandersson I was just reviewing the original remarks concerning 123-avoiding parity-alternating permutations and isn't there a bijection in the odd case as well (just reverse the sequence of values?) I'm probably missing something incredibly obvious.

Comment: @MichaelAlbert Ah, right, it is for ODD n there is that bijection, but for EVEN n, the numbers are not the same.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson So I was right - I was missing something terribly obvious - a typo :)

Comment: Having [obtained some more terms](https://gist.github.com/pjt33/395944ea3fc5dd6b02eca4d7e45c2f58) I withdraw the comment about convergence.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Nice, perhaps you can add these to https://oeis.org/A354208 ?